# jssor slider IE11 problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

I'm using jssor [on this website](http://www.henryglass.it/collezioni/vitra/) and I'm getting problems with IE 11. Of course ONLY with IE 11 because with Firefox, Safari, Chrome is everything fine.

I have already set the meta

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

and checked (as indicated on other stackoverflow thread) the dimensions specified in px.

"Debugging" with IE 11 developer console [I get this type of error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0njjoykjbh8m4nx/Screenshot%202016-03-09%2007.34.43.png?dl=0)

Suggestions? ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you specified the width of slider in IE11.

```
<div id="slider1" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 829px; height: 114px; overflow: hidden; ">
```

Comment: What do you mean? Width is set by jssor also on IE11.

Comment: jssor slider width is 829px in to IE11 solve the problem .

Comment: I cannot undestand what you mean. Could you be more clear? Thanks

Comment: set the jssor slider width in proper in supported in IE11.

Comment: use media query to for IE 11 
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .slider{
     width:829px;
}
}